# What is the number of operation for K pair quick find algorithm?

Tags: c, algorithm, big-o, code-complexity

For my code which is an implementation of the **quick find** algorithm i generally consider my code for understanding theoretical questions

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10000

main() {
    int i, t, p, q, id[N];

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) 
        id[i] = i;

    printf("Input pair p q: ");

    while (scanf("%d %d", &p, &q) == 2) {
        if (id[p] == id[q])
            printf("%d %d already connected\n", p,q);
        else {
            for (t = id[p], i = 0; i < N; i++)
                if (id[i] == t)
                    id[i] = id[q];

            printf("pair %d %d not yet connected\n", p, q);
        }

        printf("Input pair p q: ");
    }
}
```

lets consider a graph 12-6, 2-3, 0-9, 5-4, 3-10, 10-8
Supposing that in the graph there are N vertices, that there are k pairs
and that quickfind is used for the find operation, how many find
operations will be performed by the on-line connectivity algorithm?
**O(kN) Θ(kN)  O(k) Θ(k)** which there will help me find the number of operations. I know for the find operation the unit cost is O(1) because all we need for it to do is point to another array. but I am confused when concerned with a certain number of pair.

I am starting to learn this complexity analysis and the notations confused me because I know the big teta is tightly bound and is more precise for expressing complexity analysis than the Big O, but for the case of finding a number of operations, I just could not understand which one fits more.

Comment: Clearly, for any given pair at the time of entry, the code either executes a constant number of operations (printing they are already connected) or a number of operations that is bounded below and above by N. (We see the latter because the loop performs N iterations, and hence at least N steps, and it does at most some constant number of things per iteration, so there is some k such that the number of steps is less than kN.) With both cases combined, the code is bounded above by N and bounded below by 1 but not by N. Therefore, it is O(N) but is not Θ(g(N)) for any function g.

Comment: @EricPostpischil But what is changing here is the number of pairs K not N which is the number of nodes which is fixed. So in the same reasoning, you provided (O(N*k)) since N is constant it becomes O(K) no?

Comment: The k I used in my comment was intended to be an arbitrary constant coefficient, not the number of pairs. N is not usually treated as a constant in questions like this. You have written it as a “constant” in source code in the sense of what the C standard defines as constants. But N can change because source code can be edited. If you want to treat N as a constant mathematically, then the code is still bound above by N because the number of pairs cannot exceed N, so the fact that the code might perform some number of steps proportional to the number of pairs leaves it still bounded above by N.

Comment: If you include setting the initial values of array `id` in the analysis, then the number of steps is bounded below by N.

Comment: And if you consider N a constant then it would be conventional to factor it out of the asymptotic complexity analysis, no matter its (constant) value.  Whether it is constant is a choice: in what dimension(s) are you analyzing the problem size?

Comment: You mention a graph, and in that context, your `id` array is reminiscent part of a [disjoint-set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) structure.  But you don't seem to actually have any graph here, or any other part of a disjoint-set data structure, or very much disjoint-set logic.  Are you sure you've asked the question you meant to ask?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Have a look of the modified question

Comment: @EricPostpischil Have a look of the modified question

Comment: Just saying that there is a graph does not make this code implement a disjoint-set algorithm.  What you have is *not* quick find or any other disjoint-set algorithm.  Nevertheless, since you seem confident that you have in fact posed the question that you want answered, we can do that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger ok lets forget the code and think of the quick find approach for the given connection of Nodes.

Comment: Absolutely not.  We cannot in any way talk about the asymptotic complexity of an algorithm without a representation of that algorithm.  If in fact you do not mean to ask about the code actually presented, then there is no answerable question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two plausible problem dimensions with respect to which one can consider the program's asymptotic complexity: the number of nodes, `N`, and the number of queries, `k`.  Considering either one of these constant (no matter what its value) means that it factors out of the complexity analysis, because asymptotic complexity is about how some measure of the program's behavior scales with changes in the problem size.  I will consider the scaling in both of these dimensions, according to the abstract-machine semantics of the C language in which the program is expressed:

- the program spends Θ(N) operations to initialize the `id`  array, regardless of the number of queries.
- a single query requires Ω(1), O(N) steps,

  - in particular, if initially `id[p] == id[q]` then that query takes Θ(1) steps (a *type 1* query).
  - otherwise (a *type 2* query), the query reduces the number of distinct `id` values by at least 1.  There are initially `N` distinct `id` values, and that number cannot be reduced below 1, so at most `N`-1 queries can be of this type.
- The combined number of steps required for all the queries of the second type is bounded by (`N`-1) * O(`N`) = O(N<sup>2</sup>).  (`N`-1 queries, each requiring O(`N`) steps).
- I can choose a list of `N` queries that will require Ω(N<sup>2</sup>) steps overall, so there is no tighter upper bound.

  - Example: `N`-2, `N`-1; `N`-3, `N`-1; ...; 0, `N`-1.  Each query will iterate from 0 to `p`, for a total of (`N`-1)*`N`/2 iterations overall.

That gives us:

| Ω | O | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| N | N | setup |
| 1<sup>*</sup> | k | type 1 queries |
| 1<sup>*</sup> | N<sup>2</sup> | type 2 queries |
| k + N | k + N + N<sup>2</sup> | total |
| k + N | k + N<sup>2</sup> | standard reduced form |

<sup>*</sup> There are `k` queries altogether, so that is a better lower bound on the total contribution of the queries than is 1+1 = 2.

> I am starting to learn this complexity analysis and the notations confused me because I know the big teta is tightly bound and is more precise for expressing complexity analysis than the Big O, but for the case of finding a number of operations, I just could not understand which one fits more.

"More tightly bound" is a potentially misleading characterization of big-Theta.  The difference between Θ and O is that O provides only an upper bound, whereas Θ provides both an upper and a lower bound.  And in this context, one should not neglect big-Omega (Ω), which provides only a lower bound.  You can always express upper (O) and lower (Ω) asymptotic bounds for a given function, but it is not always possible to express a useful two-sided bound.

Thus, one typically starts by computing big-O.  This is not unique, but one normally tries to find as tight a bound as possible.  The above analysis addresses the tightness of the upper bound by showing that there cannot be a standard-form upper bound any tighter than the one found.

One sometimes continues by computing big-Ω.  This is useful for considering whether there are categories of inputs for which the algorithm is more efficient.  For example, insertion sort requires O(N<sup>2</sup>) steps in the average and worst cases, but it is Ω(N) overall because it sorts inputs that are already approximately in order in linear time.

If one can find a convenient functional form that can serve as both big-O and big-Ω, then that is also a useful big-Θ.  If not, then one usually just ignores big-Θ.  For example, we can always say that f(N) is Θ(f(N)), but we generally don't, because that does not give us any useful information.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. It has answered all of my questions. One additional question that crossed my mind upon looking your detailed explanation is, so does that mean if we are able to calculate it, the Big Teta complexity analysis can capture the worst case complexity analysis of an algorithm than a mere Big O?

Comment: @BitwodedS.Demissie, big-Theta captures best- and worst-case complexity at the same time.  That does not make it inherently a more precise or meaningful for worst-case complexity than is Big-O.